# Too high values with matplotlib polynomial regression (polyfit)

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, graph, regression

First, I'm sorry for my english.

Second, but the object of my post is I don't understand the result of the polyfit method applied to my data.

I'm trying to get a graph of my download speed for a day, all the values (dots) are ok but when I try to get a polynomial line, coefficients are crazy.

There is my code:

```
import matplotlib.dates as pltDates
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

dates = pltDates.date2num(timeValues)
polyLineEq = poly.polyfit(dates, downloadValues, 2)
polyLine = np.poly1d(polyLineEq)
plt.plot(xx, polyLine(xx))
```

Where timeValues is a list of the time of the speed capture and downloadValues is a list of the speed capture.

Here's entries:

- downloadValues:

  ```
  [637.7002837917455, 360.3778120551389, 619.5766620821665, 636.9486179554266, 664.3231094306018, 738.2680311720497, 243.8327594142206, 742.9903527743229, 686.7140415927788, 668.3225185514085, 676.523718421761, 649.8826401724951, 672.2717746125593, 538.7263431234095, 753.3713378294058, 741.35418932585, 236.69393515608996, 644.9317040466514]
  ```
- dates:

  ```
  [737025.89454078 737025.90627192 737025.90696364 737025.9076631 737025.90835721 737025.90905097 737025.90974066 737025.91043157 737025.91113666 737025.91183039 737025.91252393 737025.91321981 737025.91391471 737025.91460573 737025.91529649 737025.91599611 737025.91668863 737025.91738283]
  ```

And results for degrees = 2:

- polyLineEq:

  ```
  -9.52e+07 x + 0.0002777 x + 0.0001752
  ```
- polyLine(xx):

  ```
  [-5.17110011e+19 -5.17110013e+19 -5.17110014e+19 -5.17110016e+19 -5.17110018e+19 -5.17110020e+19 -5.17110022e+19 -5.17110024e+19 -5.17110026e+19 -5.17110028e+19 -5.17110030e+19 -5.17110031e+19 -5.17110033e+19 -5.17110035e+19 -5.17110037e+19 -5.17110039e+19 -5.17110041e+19 -5.17110043e+19]
  ```

for degrees = 0:

- polyLineEq:

  ```
  606.3
  ```
- polyLine(xx):

  ```
  [606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286 606.26721286]
  ```

The 0 degree makes a line which look fine but it is only a linear line (normal for degree 0).

For informations, I already tried to round values and to divide value to work with smaller values but same result.

What do I misunderstand ?

Is it possible to do what I'm looking for (a line representing the trend of my download speed)?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Have a nice day ;)

**Answer**: There is too much noise in my data to have a nice line.

Comment: I don't know why but I can't edit my post to add the "hi everyone" line at the top. Sry for that.

Comment: Concerning the comment, you may read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Concerning the question, I guess you just mixed up x and y in the fit.

Comment: If you make a scatterplot of the data, you will see that there is not much of a pattern for a second order polynomial to fit. The best you can get with such noisy data is approximately a straight horizontal line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was afraid of that but I was hoping a miracle ;)